# Muliple Plots in R - How to place segments and avoid space on the right

Tags: r

I have the following lines of code in R:

```
dat <- data.frame(mse=rnorm(1000),
                  m1=c(rep("A",333),rep("B",333),rep("C",334)),
                  m2=c(rep("E10",250),rep("E20",250),rep("E30",250),rep("E40",250)),
                  m3=c(rep("F1",200),rep("F2",200),rep("F3",200),rep("F4",200),rep("F5",200)))

par(mfrow = c(1, 3), xpd=FALSE)
par(cex = 0.6)
par(mar = c(0, 0, 0, 6), oma = c(6, 4, 0.5, 0.0))
par(tcl = -0.25)
par(mgp = c(2, 0.6, 0))

boxplot(mse ~ m1, data=dat, ylim=c(-4,4), axes=F)
axis(1, at=1:3, labels=c("A", "B", "C"))
axis(2)
boxplot(mse ~ m2, data=dat, ylim=c(-4,4), axes=F)
axis(1, at=1:4, labels=c("E10", "E20", "E30", "E40"))

par(xpd=NA)
segments(-0.5,par("usr")[3],-0.5,par("usr")[4],lty=2)
par(xpd=FALSE)

boxplot(mse ~ m3, data=dat, ylim=c(-4,4), axes=F)
axis(1, at=1:5, labels=c("F1", "F2", "F3", "F4","F5"))
box("inner")

par(xpd=NA)
segments(-1,par("usr")[3],-1,par("usr")[4],lty=2)
par(xpd=FALSE)
```

Here are my Questions:

1. The Placement of the segments for separation between the boxplots seems a little bit strange for me, can it be done easier?
2. I set right margin equal 6, but i don't wont this margin right of the last boxplot. How can i avoid this?

I realized, that the easiest way to get what I want, is to give the data as a list to the boxplot() call:

```
dat <- data.frame(mse=rnorm(1000),
                  m1=c(rep("A",333),rep("B",333),rep("C",334)),
                  m2=c(rep("E10",250),rep("E20",250),rep("E30",250),rep("E40",250)),
                  m3=c(rep("F1",200),rep("F2",200),rep("F3",200),rep("F4",200),rep("F5",200)))

datList <- list(A=dat[dat$m1=="A",]$mse,
                B=dat[dat$m1=="B",]$mse,
                C=dat[dat$m1=="C",]$mse,
                E10=dat[dat$m2=="E10",]$mse,
                E20=dat[dat$m2=="E20",]$mse,
                E30=dat[dat$m2=="E30",]$mse,
                E40=dat[dat$m2=="E40",]$mse,
                F1=dat[dat$m3=="F1",]$mse,
                F2=dat[dat$m3=="F2",]$mse,
                F3=dat[dat$m3=="F3",]$mse,
                F4=dat[dat$m3=="F4",]$mse,
                F5=dat[dat$m3=="F5",]$mse)



par(mfrow = c(1, 1))
par(cex = 0.6)
par(mar = c(0, 3.5, 0, 0), oma = c(6, 4, 0.5, 0.5))
par(tcl = -0.25)
par(mgp = c(2, 0.6, 0))


boxplot(datList, at = c(1:3, 5:8, 10:14), xlim = c(1, 14), axes = F, ylab="mse")
box(); axis(2, las = 1); 
axis(1, labels = c("A", "B", "C", "E10", "E20", "E30", "E40", "F1", "F2", "F3", "F4", "F5"), at = c(1:3, 5:8, 10:14))

abline(v = c(4, 9), lty = 2)
```

Then I get the following result:

[image: boxplot]
<sub>(source: [googledrive.com](https://googledrive.com/host/0B7-aTfJSPpg7UjduVXJFMnNMc1k/boxplot.png))</sub>

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(gridExtra)
ggp <- ggplot(dat)
p1  <- ggp + geom_boxplot(aes(x=m1, y=mse))
p2  <- ggp + geom_boxplot(aes(x=m2, y=mse))
p3  <- ggp + geom_boxplot(aes(x=m3, y=mse))

grid.arrange(p1,p2,p3,nrow=1)
```

[image]

In response to @Paul, you can:

```
library(reshape2)
xx=melt(dat, id.vars="mse", measure.vars=c("m1","m2","m3"),
   variable.name="facet", value.name="facet.variable")
ggplot(xx) + 
   geom_boxplot(aes(x=facet.variable,y=mse)) + 
   facet_grid(~facet,scales="free") + 
   labs(x="")
```

[image]

I just thought the other way was simpler and easier to understand. Note that the actual data is different this time because the sample dataset is generated using `rnorm(...)`.

Comment: Why are you using `grid.arrange` in stead of `facet_wrap`?